# Compare current date with date for the nodes

Tags: xslt

I'm having a small issue with the XSLT ...

Basically i have following xml:

```
<Root>
 <Node>
  <Prop1></Prop1>
  <Prop2></Prop2>
  <Date>03/05/2013</Date>
  ...
 </Node>
 <Node>
  <Prop1></Prop1>
  <Prop2></Prop2>
  <Date>01/01/2012</Date>
  ...
 </Node>
</Root>
```

From this i generate a table it looks something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>       
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">
        <u>
        Table: 
        </u>    
    </th>
</tr> 
<xsl:for-each select="Root/Node[current-date() < date]">    
    <xsl:sort select="date" />          
            <tr>                
                <td><xsl:value-of select="prop1"/></td>
                <td>
                        ...       
                </td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
            </tr> 
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

I would like to get only the nodes which the date is overdue, basically date < currentdate

Any idea how i could achieve it?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm using xslt 1.0 :(

Comment: Ok, do the date values in your source data have to be in the format MM/dd/yyyy, or can they be formatted as yyyy-MM-dd? Having them in the former format will make them hard to work with and sort.

Comment: I get this passed with the parameter: 2013-03-14T10:47:50Z

Comment: Ok, that value will be good, but I'm referring to the dates in the source XML. The XML you have above shows them in MM/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please firstly bear in mind that XPath is case sensative and that `Node` will not match an element if its name is actually `Node1` or `Node2`.

Supposing that you are working with XSLT 1.0, there isn't a built-in way to get the current date, so you would need to pass it in as a parameter.  If you can get that working, something like this should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="currentDate" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">
          <u>
            Table:
          </u>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/*[translate($currentDate, 'T:-', '') &lt; 
                                          translate(Date, 'T:-', '')]">
        <xsl:sort select="Date" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Root/*">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Prop1"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry but could you please return to previous example, as it was xstl 1.0 and i managed to pass a parameter and this date parameter has value like this for example: 2013-03-14T10:47:50Z

Comment: I've reverted my answer, but in order for it to the work, the dates in your input XML also have to be in `yyyy-MM-dd...` format.